# Pseudo parameter in cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I'm using the below simple template and trying to list the region in parameter section using Pseudo parameter AWS::Region, however getting the below error while trying to update the stack :

```
Failed to retrieve external values
```

Image posted here  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUcoo.png

Nothing reporting on cloudtrail :

```
"responseElements": {
        "parameters": [
            {
                "parameterType": "List<AWS::Region>",
                "noEcho": false,
                "parameterKey": "S3"
            }
```

Below are my template details :

```
Parameters: 
 Region:
  Type: List<AWS::Region>
  Default: us-east-1

Resources:
###
```

Can someone give an advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its **not possible**. You have to use `CommaDelimitedList`.